# PostgreSQL TEMP table alternating between exist and not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.2, with Toad client on Mac. Auto-commit is set to ON.
I first created a simple temp table like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE demo_pairs
AS
WITH t (name, value) AS (VALUES ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Then something weird happens when I ran:

```
SELECT * FROM demo_pairs;
```

Every time I run the select (without re-running the create), it alternates between successfully selecting the values and error with table does not exist!

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with the same version of the database server and the 'psql' command-line client.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

> TEMPORARY or TEMP
>
> If specified, the table is created as a temporary table. Temporary
>   tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or
>   optionally at the end of the current transaction (see ON COMMIT
>   below). Existing permanent tables with the same name are not visible
>   to the current session while the temporary table exists, unless they
>   are referenced with schema-qualified names. Any indexes created on a
>   temporary table are automatically temporary as well.

If you use session pooler that can close session for your or just close it yourself (eg network problem), the temp table will be dropped.
Also you can create it the way it is dropped on transaction end as well:

> ON COMMIT
>
> The behavior of temporary tables at the end of a transaction block can
>   be controlled using ON COMMIT. The three options are:
>
> PRESERVE ROWS
>
> No special action is taken at the ends of transactions. This is the
>   default behavior.
>
> DELETE ROWS
>
> All rows in the temporary table will be deleted at the end of each
>   transaction block. Essentially, an automatic TRUNCATE is done at each
>   commit.
>
> DROP
>
> The temporary table will be dropped at the end of the current transaction block.